# Sum of the Reverse of a Non-Palindromic Number is a Palindrome

Tags: python, loops, palindrome

I have an assignment where I'm prompting the user to enter a starting and an ending number. Using this range I have to check if the starting number is less than the ending number and that they both are greater than one. Then I need to check all the numbers in the range (inclusive) to see if they're a palindrome or not, if they're not, I need to reverse the number and add it to the original until I get a palindrome. I also need to keep track of the cycle length each time I go through the loop and reverse a number.

This is what I have so far, and I don't really understand where I'm going wrong.

```
def rev_num(n):
  rev_n = 0
  while (n > 0):
    rev_n = rev_n * 10 + (n % 10)
    n = n // 10
  return rev_n

def is_palindromic(n):
  return (n == rev_num(n))

def main():
  # Prompt the user to enter the starting number of the range.
  start = eval (input ("Enter starting number of the range: "))

  # Prompt the user to enter the ending number of the range.
  finish = eval (input ("Enter ending number of the range: "))

  # Check that the starting and ending number are greater than 1 and start is smaller than ending number.
  while (start >= finish or start < 1 or finish < 1):
  start = eval (input ("Enter starting number of the range: "))
  finish = eval (input ("Enter ending number of the range: "))

  # Initialize variables for cycle length and max cycle length.
  cycle_length = 0
  max_cycle_length = 0
  max_num = 0
  n = start

  # Write a loop that goes through all the numbers.
  while (n <= finish):
  cycle_length = 0

  # Write the conditions for the Palidromic Reverse Sum.
    while (is_palindromic(n) == False):
      n += rev_num(n)
      cycle_length = cycle_length + 1

  #Increment the counter and assign the cycle length to the max cycle length  if > or =.
    if (cycle_length >= max_cycle_length):
      max_cycle_length = cycle_length
      max_num = n
    counter += 1

   # Print the results
   print ("The number " + str(max_num) + " has the longest cycle length of " + str(max_cycle_length) + ".")
```

main()

Comment: Use `int(input())` instead of `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting bad results because your inner loop modifies `n`, which the outer loop expects to only increase by one at a time. I think you need to use a different variable for the number in the inner loop. It might also make sense to use a `for` loop for `n` (but since you *also* need to record `n`'s value in the `max_cycle_length` check, this isn't enough to fix the larger problems).

```
for n in range(start, finish+1):      # for loops are nicer than while loops
    x = n                             # use n's value as initial value for x
    cycle_length = 0
    while not is_palindromic(x):      # inner loop modifies x not n
        x += rev_num(x)
        cycle_count += 1
    if cycle_count > max_cycle_count:
        max_cycle_count = cycle_count
        max_num = n                   # use n again here
```